# ReportingServicesTools module for SSRS always uses current user credentials

Tags: powershell, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm currently logged as DomainA\blevitt.  However, only DomainB\blevitt has access to SSRS.  If I run the script below...

```
$ssrsCredential = Get-Credential
Connect-RsReportServer -ReportServerUri $reportServerUrl -Credential $ssrsCredential -Verbose 
Write-RsCatalogItem -ReportServerUri $reportServerUrl -RsFolder "/$folder" -Path '.\Time Cost vs Tracked.rdl' -Overwrite -Verbose
```

...and specify DomainB\blevitt at the Get-Credential prompt I receive:

> The permissions granted to user 'DomainA\blevitt' are insufficient 
>       for performing this operation

Note that it used my current powershell DomainA account rather than the DomainB credential I passed to Get-Credential.  I also tried passing the DomainB credential directly to the -Credential arg of Write-RsCatalogItem.

I know I can start my powershell session as a different user, but I'm still wondering why the -Credentail param doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: It sounds like its acknowledging the credentials but stating they do not have sufficient rights on the Reporting server.

Comment: Might be better to raise this as an issue on the github repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/ReportingServicesTools/issues